# npm start problem: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I've got some problem with starting app by using 'npm start'. After create react files folder and using that command I can see:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! weatherapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weatherapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I want to add that I've used react before. I was running code the same way but everything was good. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are writing the `npm start` command to correct package where your package.json resides.
More likely it seems you don't have react script installed.
Can you try installing script with following command.

```
npm i react-scripts
```

This may solve your problem. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove node_modules and package.log or yarn.lock file also. and run `npm install` again. Should solve your problem.